# Can't seem to make a simple Hello World app

Tags: django, django-urls

[image of 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqvMx.png)  sorry in advance if my format is off this is my first time posting to here. I'm having a really hard time getting started with Django I've followed the tutorial on the https://djangoforbeginners.com/hello-world/ and when I finished I still get the standard landing page is there something that I'm not getting ?

```
 #from project.urls
from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import path, include  # new

 urlpatterns = [
path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
path("", include("pages.urls"))  # new
]

# from pages.urls
from django.urls import path
   from . import views

   urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    ]

  
  #from pages.views
  from django.shortcuts import render


  from django.http import HttpResponse


  def index(request):
     return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello, World!</h1>")
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting the 404 error page as if is can't see the url that I want it to point too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project.urls, you have to mension **app.urls**, so your code must be:

```
 urlpatterns = [
  path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
  path("", include("app.urls"))  # new
 ]
```

In settings.py, just mension app as `pages` :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
 #defualt apps
 "pages",
]
```

Comment: Sorry I labeled my work a little funny( updated the post to clarify) so the name of my app is pages thats why I have pages.urls that is the correct format then right ?

Comment: I checked the settings.py as well and made sure to add pages. It still gives me the 404 error.

Comment: Thanks for your help I think there is something terribly wrong in my vscode set up because I moved my same code to Pycharm and it worked on the first go.